# Struts/Spring with Tiles error-page

Tags: spring, error-handling, internationalization, struts, tiles

I'm still a newbie, and I'm not sure how else to implement custom error pages.

I'm using tiles, and I believe this project has the struts2 and spring framework mangled together.

I did the basic stuff in my web.xml:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsps/404error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Works perfect - so long as I hard-code all the parts of the tiles and don't use i18n. As soon as I place a:

```
<s:text name="404.error.title" />
```

It gets the error:

> The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.
>   This is usually caused by using Struts
>   tags without the associated filter.
>   Struts tags are only usable when the
>   request has passed through its servlet
>   filter, which initializes the Struts
>   dispatcher needed for this tag. -
>   [unknown location]

Servlet? There are no servlets-things in the 100+ code lying around.
Lots of struts.xml and appContext.xml stuff. I'm not sure what to do.

And I don't want to put tons of errorpage tags in all my jsps.

But really, I just want to know if there is a way to make a site-wide error-page that directs to an action/tile page. Like the < error-page > code above.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the Struts2 FilterDispatcher configured in your web.xml.  Here is an example configuration:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Hm... Actually I was too quick to decide it would work...

I tried using both struts2 filters and commenting out the previous struts2 filter, but it seems to have no effect.

<filter-name>struts2-old</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>

Still the same servlet error...